# C program that displays all numbers in between the two integer inputs in ascending order

Tags: c

I tried to do this activity but there is always an extra "result" in the output
output:

```
Enter integer a:10
Enter integer b:1

Result: 1
Result: 10
Result: 9
Result: 8
Result: 7
Result: 6
Result: 5
Result: 4
Result: 3
Result: 2
Result: 1
Result: 0
```

ideal output:

```
Enter integer a:10
Enter integer b:1
Result: 10
Result: 9
Result: 8
Result: 7
Result: 6
Result: 5
Result: 4
Result: 3
Result: 2
Result: 1
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a;
  int b;

  printf("Enter integer a:");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter integer b:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  do {
    printf("Result: %d\n", b);
    b--;
  } while (a <= b);

  do {
    printf("Result: %d\n", a);
    a--;
  } while (a >= b);
}
```

Comment: Please add a clear, specific question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are *two* extra results. There is also an unwanted `0` at the end, because you decremented `b`. If `a < b` then swap them. Or verify the input and don't *allow* user to enter `b` greater than `a`.

Comment: _C program that displays all numbers in between the two integer inputs in **ascending order**_. The result you have shown in your question is in descending order and not ascending order.

Comment: Shark tales,  If input was `a==1` then `b==10`, what output would be the ideal output?  Same as if input was `a==10` then `b==1`?

Comment: "all numbers ... in **ascending** order" and "ideal output: Result: 10 Result: 9 ... Result: 1" is a contradiction as the output is **descending**.  Shark tales, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first while loop that generates the unwanted output (the first `Result: 1`) and modifies the limit used by the second loop (the last `Result: 0`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a;
  int b;

  printf("Enter integer a:");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter integer b:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  do {
    printf("Result: %d\n", a);
    a--;
  } while (a >= b);
}
```

So after taking the additional requirement into account:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a;
  int b;

  printf("Enter integer a:");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter integer b:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  if(b > a)
  {
      do {
        printf("Result: %d\n", b);
        b--;
      } while (a <= b);
  }
  else
  {
      do {
        printf("Result: %d\n", a);
        a--;
      } while (a >= b);
  }
}
```

I prefer a `if` statement since it communicates the intention clearer than changing the `do ... while` to `while`.

So after Davids comment ... the most concise version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int a, b;
  int temp;

  printf("Enter integer a:");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Enter integer b:");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  // Swap so that a < b.
  if(b > a)
  {
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }

  // output
  do {
    printf("Result: %d\n", a);
    a--;
  } while (a >= b);
}
```

Comment: but it wont display the same thing when b<a

Comment: @Shark_tales Then indicate the addition constraint (b<a) in you question that is also an requirement.

Comment: It worked. thank you

Comment: You can also just swap `a` and `b` if `a > b` and avoid code duplication that way. You can check `a == b` and exit with a message if they are equal.

Comment: @David_C._Rankin I thought about a swap but was in a hurry.

Comment: @David_C._Rankin Now if equal it only prints the number once.

Answer (score 2):

use `while` instead of `do-while`, `do-while` will always run one time.